# exec command with parameters in Go?

Tags: bash, go, command

In my shell, I can exec command `acme.sh --issue --dns -d exmaple.com --yes-I-know-dns-manual-mode-enough-go-ahead-please` and get output.

now I want to do that in go, and my code like:

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "acme.sh --issue --dns -d exmaple.com --yes-I-know-dns-manual-mode-enough-go-ahead-please");
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("issue failed with error: %s\n", err)
}
fmt.Printf("combined out:\n%s\n", string(out))
```

but I got error `exit status 1`.

and as the comment said, I separate argument:

`exec.Command("bash", "-c", "acme.sh", "--issue", "--dns", "-d exmaple.com", "--yes-I-know-dns-manual-mode-enough-go-ahead-please");`

but the result is that it exec `acme.sh` without parameters.

Comment: Your English is fine. Thanks for updating the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exclude `exit status 1` from err will get right result.

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "acme.sh --issue --dns -d exmaple.com --yes-I-know-dns-manual-mode-enough-go-ahead-please");
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil && err.Error() != "exit status 1" {
    log.Fatalf("issue failed with error: %s\n", err)
}
fmt.Printf("combined out:\n%s\n", string(out))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using this script as acme.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$*"
```

with the program as given in the same directory the error you report occurs

However, if I add the current directory to the shell PATH

```
export PATH=.:$PATH
```

Then the program executes as hoped for, in the case of my version

```
$ go run c.go 
combined out:
--issue --dns -d exmaple.com --yes-I-know-dns-manual-mode-enough-go-ahead-please
```

Ok so that's the case when the bash -c takes a single string as the command (more about that in a moment)

If the command is issued like this

```
    cmd := exec.Command("acme.sh", "--issue", "--dns", "-d exmaple.com", "--
yes-I-know-dns-manual-mode-enough-go-ahead-please")
```

Then as the later edits to your question state, the command acme.sh is run without arguments.

The problem is with the way that `bash -c` behaves.

From the man page

> bash interprets the following options when it
>          is invoked:
>
> ```
>    -c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from  the
>              first non-option argument command_string.  If there are argu‐
>              ments after the command_string,  they  are  assigned  to  the
>              positional parameters, starting with $0.
> ```

In your case what this means is that the first arg to `bash -c` is accepted as a command.  The other args are lost as they are positional args to the new bash shell and not to the `acme.sh` command

See this for more details on `bash -c` https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144514/add-arguments-to-bash-c

Lastly, what I would do in this situation: Skip the `"bash" "-c"`, ensure that the script has a correct bang line and rely on the kernel binfmt handler